Cannot copy file to windows 11 file system - if you are running this code in the linux server
I'm doing a download from java apps running on linux.  The following is the code:
    public void downloadCopyToFile(String filename, String outFilename) throws IOException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(filename);

            log.info("downloading file from: "+url.toString());
            log.info("export to: "+outFilename);
            
            File outFile = new File(outFilename);
            
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, outFile);          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        
    }

The parameters for the method is as follows:
filename = https://192.168.100.100:8443/generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx
outFilename = c:\temp\generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx
When I run this in windows, it can save to c:\temp, but when I move it to the server running linux, it gives me error 500 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: c:\temp\generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx
I'm not sure whther copyURLToFile actually understands that this must be written to windows, because if I change the outFilename to /temp/generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx it actually writes to the linux file system.
I have been working on this for the last 3 days.  Please help.

but when I move it to the server running linux: do I correctly understand that you want  the code running on a linux server to download the file to a different computer that uses Windows? How should the linux server know on which Windows computer it should store the file? On my computer or on your computer?

Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by "I'm not sure whther copyURLToFile actually understands that this must be written to windows"? A method does not "understand" anything. This one takes the path you give it and hands it over to the system to get back a file handle where it can save the file contents. If you give it a path in MS-Windows notation this certainly won't work on a linux system. How should a linux system save something to a windows file system? It might be that you mounted some windows file system into your linux file system. But then it is part of that.

Keep in mind that the "drive letter" you see in windows path notations does not make any sense in any other system. Even if that method tries to "translate" your windows path notation to a linux path this would not work, unless you actually have a folder /C/temp/ on that system. Which I doubt.

Why is this question tagged with "apache" and "download"? I suggest to remove both tags.

@arkascha Ah - I've typed in wrong text to my comment, I'll delete as not relevant given the path starts c:

Thanks everyone for the comments.  So, the question is how to specify "I want to copy to windows file system" using the above code?  Or I'm getting it all wrong?

If you mount your windows file system under a linux path (like /mnt/c) you can copy the file to that file system (by using a path like /mnt/c/temp/generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx). But since you mentioned "server" I suspect that you want to write the file from to server to a Windows clients file system and that is not possible - the server doesn't have access to the clients file system.

@ThomasKläger Thanks for the comment.

On your Linux box, what does the following show? curl -I https://192.168.100.100:8443/generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx

If I am reading your question correctly (it is not very clear!) the problem is arising because you are trying to write to a file called
  c:\temp\generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx

on a Linux system.
That didn't work.  It would have tried to file whose name started with a c: in the current directory.  The exception says that your application didn't have permission to do that.  Probably the current directory's ownership, access mode and/or ACL doesn't allow it.
But even if it allowed it, that would have been the wrong thing to do.
Drive letters (like "c:") are only a thing on Windows.  On Linux, Unix, MacOS and so forth, "c:" would be interpreted as part of a simple file name.


I'm not sure whether copyURLToFile actually understands that this must be written to windows, because if I change the outFilename to "/temp/generalLedger20240629140353.xlsx" it actually writes to the linux file system.

(Yes, that's the correct way to do it.   Assuming you want to write to the Linux file systems.)
Java's copyURLToFile doesn't understand that you want to write that to windows.  And even if it understood what you wanted, Java on Linux doesn't know how to write files to Windows.  When are running a program on a Linux system, the file system is the local >>Linux<< file system on >>this<< machine, not a file system on some other machine.
But maybe that's not what you mean ...
One possibility is that you have a dual boot machine (Linux and Windows) and you have booted Linux and want to write to the machine's Windows file system.  That is possible ... but the Linux OS will need to mount the Windows NTFS (or FAT) file system.  You will need to use Linux pathname syntax: no drive letters!
Another possibility is that the Windows file system you are trying to write to is a Windows (SMB) file share.  Once again, to do that Linux needs to mount the file share, and you then use Linux pathname syntax to access the files.

Thanks for the answer.  I was reading this https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file and other posting to download file from the server.  Any other alternatives to donwload file?

What I meant was that the ref from https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file and other posting to download file from the server gave me a wrong perception and they are just to copy files.  My objective is to produce a file in the server and allows user to download to the local windows machine.  Any suggestion to do that?

I don't understand.  When the user runs your program on their Windows machine, they >will< successfully download the file to their local machine.  (And on Linux too ... provided that you use a Linux pathname.)

I got it now.  The above code must be run in a local client windows machine in order to download the file from the server.  The code CANNOT run in the server to allow file download to the client.  Hopefully this clear the confusion.

That is correct.   A program running on one machine cannot (directly) write to another machine's file system.
